# ffmpeg genereated mp4 have no sound

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, mp4, aac

I have a mp4 file with two audio channel,as below.[image]

Then I use `ffmpeg -i 70_1.mp4 -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:00:10 -hide_banner 777.mp4`
 to cut a slice, but the generated file lost sound.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Default [stream selection behavior](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Stream-selection) is to choose one stream per stream type, so you have to tell it you want all of the streams with the [`-map` option](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options):

```
ffmpeg -i 70_1.mp4 -ss 00:00:00 -t 00:00:10 -map 0 777.mp4
```